# Using display:table with extra tags leads to cells that aren't full height

Tags: css

I'm generating a DOM that I want to display as a table. Using `display: table` and associated CSS values works great for the following:

```css
.my-table {
    display: table;
}

.my-row {
    display: table-row;
}

.my-cell {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 10em;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-table">
    <div class="my-row">
        <div class="my-cell">HEADER with very very long content that wraps, making all cells in the row taller</div>
        <div class="my-cell">cell one</div>
        <div class="my-cell">cell two</div>
        <div class="my-cell">cell three</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see by running the snippet, all cells are the same height as the first cell on the left.

Sadly, this no longer works when introducing an arbitrary node (CSS is identical):

```css
.my-table {
    display: table;
}

.my-row {
    display: table-row;
}

.my-cell {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 10em;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-table">
    <div class="my-row">
        <div class="my-cell">HEADER with very very long content that wraps, making all cells in the row taller</div>
        <my-el>
            <div class="my-cell">cell one</div>
            <div class="my-cell">cell two</div>
            <div class="my-cell">cell three</div>
        </my-el>
    </div>
</div>
```

This time, the cell heights are NOT the same as the tallest cell in the row. How can this be addressed? Here is a fiddle to play around with: https://jsfiddle.net/7a9unbmp/1/

Why is that arbitrary element there? The DOM nodes are being generated by Angular, which inserts some nodes. Ideally, I'll find a solution that doesn't involve having to mess with the generated structure (or at least not too much).

Why use CSS table display instead of an actual HTML `table`? It's more forgiving: if any non-table elements are found within a `table`, they will get reparented by the browser and completely break things... Also, using normal elements allows me to wrap groups of rows to hide/show them according to the (sub-)group they belong to...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to "skip" unnecessary elements in a nesting structure when using CSS display:table?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32992207/is-there-a-way-to-skip-unnecessary-elements-in-a-nesting-structure-when-using)

Comment: Although my issue is the same, I'd rather not use that solution: the DOM within the "table" is relatively complex, and going through it to reparent the child nodes would likely introduce issues (as Angular will be regenerating the DOM on its own and reinserting the unwanted nodes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following CSS on your `<my-el>` element

```
my-el {
    display:inline-table; /* or inline-flex*/
    height:100%;
}
```

### [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/danield770/7a9unbmp/2/)

```css
.my-table {
  display: table;
}
.my-row {
  display: table-row;
}
.my-cell {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 10em;
  background-color: blue;
}
my-el {
  display: inline-table; /* or inline-flex */
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-table">
  <div class="my-row">
    <div class="my-cell">HEADER with very very long content that wraps, making all cells in the row taller</div>
    <div class="my-cell">cell one</div>
    <div class="my-cell">cell two</div>
    <div class="my-cell">cell three</div>
  </div>
</div>

<br/>
<br/>
<br/>

<div class="my-table">
  <div class="my-row">
    <div class="my-cell">HEADER with very very long content that wraps, making all cells in the row taller</div>
    <my-el>
      <div class="my-cell">cell one</div>
      <div class="my-cell">cell two</div>
      <div class="my-cell">cell three</div>
    </my-el>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: My savior! Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a my-el or alternatively set a fixed line heigth and giving that element said heigth.

```
CSS
.example {

 line-heigth: 80px;
 }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't really in my situation: some rows will be much larger than others, so the sizing needs to be dynamic.